# Access Query - How Do I Write a Query to Use Data Associated with Dates in the Past?

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a query that calculates daily investment returns. The formula would be:

```
Market Value at date t / Market Value at date t - 1
```

Where I'm struggling is how to tell access to grab the market value from date t minus 1. My current TotalMarketValue table looks like this:

```
TotalMV    Date
100        11/01/2016
110        11/02/2016
132        11/03/2016
```

I want to create a new query that divides the 132 by 110 to produce 20% daily return for 11/03/2016; and then 110 / 100 = 10% for 11/02/2016.

The output would look as follows.

```
DailyReturn       Date
10%               11/02/2016
20%               11/03/2016
```

I'm just not sure how to tell Access to use the market value from a day in the past as the denominator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Thanks for the help @Fionnuala. I was looking at my problem and I think I'm going to simplify what I need. Rather than calculate a daily return, I simply want my query to show the market value of the prior day as well. So the output that I'm now looking for would look something like this:

```
TotalMV         Date                PrevMV
100             11/01/16  
110             11/02/16            100
132             11/03/16            110
```

The problem with the [date minus 1] that I foresee is on weekends/holidays, when I wont have any market value date.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few notes. You should use a form to enter the date. This is very rough:

```
SELECT t.totalmv,
       t.adate,
       (SELECT TOP 1 adate
        FROM   table2
        WHERE  adate < [enter date]
        ORDER  BY adate DESC)                      AS [t minus 1],
       (SELECT TOP 1 totalmv
        FROM   table2 b
        WHERE  adate < [enter date]
        ORDER  BY adate DESC)                      AS [mv minus 1],
       Format([totalmv] / [mv minus 1], "percent") AS division
FROM   table2 t
WHERE  (( ( t.adate ) = [enter date] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @Fionnuala. Here is the solution to my edited question for anyone that is interested:

```
SELECT TotalMarketValue.SettlementDate, TotalMarketValue.TotalMV, 
(SELECT Top 1 Temp.TotalMV FROM TotalMarketValue AS Temp 
WHERE Temp.SettlementDate<TotalMarketValue.SettlementDate
ORDER BY Temp.SettlementDate DESC) AS PreviousTotalMV
FROM TotalMarketValue;
```